# Semantic Syntax Markup Language (SSML) on blueprint?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I was trying to use SSML syntax while filling out the Alexa blueprint skill form but then I got an error. Is there a way the form can support SSML?

Entry:

```
<amazon:effect name="whispered">I am not a real human.</amazon:effect>.
```

Error:

```
Special characters are not supported. However, Alexa can speak special characters ( @ # $ % _ + = | ; ), if enclosed in single quotes ( '@' ).
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but (currently) you can only use PlainText in blueprint based skills, because (as you mentioned the error message) the special characters needed for an XML based syntax are not supported by the form.

Just an additional hint to your SSML text, if you want to use it in a regular skill:

As a XML based syntax it needs embracing speak tag and no outside/final dot.

```
<speak><amazon:effect name="whispered">I am not a real human.</amazon:effect></speak>
```

https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/speech-synthesis-markup-language-ssml-reference.html